# Deploy ubuntu with MAAS fails

Tags: boot, disk, maas, kvm-virtualization

I have a problem with the Ubuntu deploying with MAAS.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a KVM virtual machine. 
The boot with `pxe` works, I see the login prompt during the deploying, the server connect the repository and get the messages `SUCCESS`.
But if I start the VM there is no data on the vm hard disk.

Does someone know this problem and have an idea what's wrong?

greets schlussbilanz